# How to get sum of two alias tables result in main result in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need little help to simplify my mysql query. I have three tables. One for main user records, second for bonus points for each user (multiple records for each user) and third for result point (multiple record for each user).

### **QUERY**

```
SELECT u.*, (SELECT SUM(ub.Points) 
FROM nba_user_bonus AS ub 
WHERE ub.UserId = u.Id) AS BonusPoints,  
(SELECT SUM(ur.Points) 
FROM nba_user_result AS ur 
WHERE ur.UserId = u.Id) AS ResultPoints 
FROM nba_users AS u 
WHERE u.Status = 'Enable' 
ORDER BY u.Id ASC
```

Here I am getting each user with total bonus point and total result points, But I need TatalPoint (sum of result point and bonus points) for each user order by that TotalPoints DESC. In sort, I want list of users with points for leader board.
Please ask me if you will need any further detail for db tables. 
Hoping for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is reasonable.  You can just add the two values together:

```
SELECT u.*,
       ((SELECT SUM(ub.Points) FROM nba_user_bonus ub  WHERE ub.UserId = u.Id) + 
        (SELECT SUM(ur.Points) FROM nba_user_result ur WHERE ur.UserId = u.Id)
       ) as TotalPoints
FROM nba_users AS u
WHERE u.Status = 'Enable' 
ORDER BY TotalPoints desc;
```

If you need all three values, you can use a subquery or repeat the calculations:

```
SELECT u.*, (BonusPoints + ResultPoints) as TotalPoints
FROM (SELECT u.*,
             (SELECT SUM(ub.Points) FROM nba_user_bonus ub  WHERE ub.UserId = u.Id) as BonusPoints,
             (SELECT SUM(ur.Points) FROM nba_user_result ur WHERE ur.UserId = u.Id) as ResultPoints
      FROM nba_users AS u
      WHERE u.Status = 'Enable' 
     ) u
ORDER BY TotalPoints desc;
```

You can also phrase this as joins with group bys.  However, this method with subqueries in the `select` may be faster than that approach.

EDIT:

To handle `NULL`s in the first case, use `ifnull()` or `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT u.*,
       (coalesce((SELECT SUM(ub.Points) FROM nba_user_bonus ub  WHERE ub.UserId = u.Id), 0) + 
        coalesce((SELECT SUM(ur.Points) FROM nba_user_result ur WHERE ur.UserId = u.Id), 0)
       ) as TotalPoints
FROM nba_users AS u
WHERE u.Status = 'Enable' 
ORDER BY TotalPoints desc;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help with detail explanation. I tried same as your first option but I tried to using alias for sub queries. Now its working fine but getting one problem. If any one is null value than   it is giving null result. First user showing 900 (400 + 500). but second user showing empty as there is only 100 for first sub query and no record for second sub query. is there any solution please?

Comment: I need one more help to extend this suggested query, Can you please?

Comment: @DineshGajjar . . . Then you should ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of subquerying in the SELECT portion of the statement, use a join. Then add a GROUP BY at the end so you get a distinct U.ID and UR and UB totals.

```
SELECT 
    u.ID,
    SUM(ub.Points)+     SUM(ur.Points) as TotalPoints
FROM 
    nba_users AS u
    LEFT OUTER JOIN nba_user_bonus as ub on
        u.ID = ub.userid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN nba_user_result as ur on
        u.ID = ur.userid

WHERE u.STATUS = 'Enable'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY u.Id ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But its giving me wrong result. giving total sum of all users at first row of records. Thanks you for your effort.

Comment: This may result in unexpected results